# How to implement call by name in C#?

Tags: c#, compiler-theory, callbyname

Can anyone tell me how I can implement **Call By Name** in **C#**?

Comment: What version of C# are you using (what is you Visual Studio version)?

Comment: A compiler in C#, who'd of thunk it!

Comment: @0xA3: It doesn't matter, it should be like a compiler or something like that...

Comment: @Dr TJ: How would that not matter when you ask about an *implementation*? Different versions of C# have different features available.

Comment: @0xA3: because this is just about algorithm and I can't use any compilers ability... Just i have to do implementations in one programming language

Comment: @Dr TJ: Yes, and C# 4.0 is a different programming language than C# 2.0, complete with different, improved capabilities for handling precisely this issue.

Comment: Do you want to use C# as if it were a call-by-name language or do you want to implement a language that uses call-by-name in C#? The "compiler-theory" tag makes it look like the latter, but everyone seems to have answered the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=VS.80%29.aspx):

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class CallMethodByName
{
   string name;

   CallMethodByName (string name)
   {
      this.name = name;
   }

   public void DisplayName()      // method to call by name
   {
      Console.WriteLine (name);   // prove we called it
   }

   static void Main()
   {
      // Instantiate this class
      CallMethodByName cmbn = new CallMethodByName ("CSO");

      // Get the desired method by name: DisplayName
      MethodInfo methodInfo = 
         typeof (CallMethodByName).GetMethod ("DisplayName");

      // Use the instance to call the method without arguments
      methodInfo.Invoke (cmbn, null);
   }
}
```

Comment: This is not call-by-name.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_name

Comment: The OP most likely refers to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_name which is different from dynamically calling a method based on the name.

Comment: Given they accepted this answer, I suspect the OP was actually referring to VB.NET's [CallByName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.callbyname)

Answer (score 9):

Pass a lambda function instead of a value.  C# is eagerly evaluated so in order to defer execution so that each site re-evaluates the supplied arguments you need to wrap the arguments in a function.

```
int blah = 1;

void Foo(Func<int> somethingToDo)  {
  int result1 = somethingToDo(); // result1 = 100

  blah = 5;
  int result2 = somethingToDo(); // result = 500
}

Foo(() => blah * 100);
```

You can use the [Lazy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx) class if you're in .NET 4.0 to get a similar (but not identical) effect.  `Lazy` memoizes the result so that repeated accesses do not have to re-evaluate the function.

Comment: To those who are wondering, using `Lazy<T>` will result in *call-by-need*.

Comment: A lambda function is one way to generate a `delegate`.

Comment: @Steven: Indeed, however strictly speaking lambdas are not delegates but implicitly convertible to matching delegate types.

Comment: That distinction would matter if we were to manipulate it as an expression tree, but doesn't happen to make any difference here.

Answer (score 3):

```
public enum CallType
{
/// <summary>
/// Gets a value from a property.
/// </summary>
Get,
/// <summary>
/// Sets a value into a property.
/// </summary>
Let,
/// <summary>
/// Invokes a method.
/// </summary>
Method,
/// <summary>
/// Sets a value into a property.
/// </summary>
Set
}

/// <summary>
/// Allows late bound invocation of
/// properties and methods.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="target">Object implementing the property or method.</param>
/// <param name="methodName">Name of the property or method.</param>
/// <param name="callType">Specifies how to invoke the property or method.</param>
/// <param name="args">List of arguments to pass to the method.</param>
/// <returns>The result of the property or method invocation.</returns>
public static object CallByName(object target, string methodName, CallType callType, params object[] args)
{
  switch (callType)
  {
    case CallType.Get:
      {
        PropertyInfo p = target.GetType().GetProperty(methodName);
        return p.GetValue(target, args);
      }
    case CallType.Let:
    case CallType.Set:
      {
        PropertyInfo p = target.GetType().GetProperty(methodName);
        p.SetValue(target, args[0], null);
        return null;
      }
    case CallType.Method:
      {
        MethodInfo m = target.GetType().GetMethod(methodName);
        return m.Invoke(target, args);
      }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_name), then I think the closest equivalent would be delegates.

Comment: delegates? can you explain how?! do you mean, just using a delegate?

Comment: Ron Warholic's example is an example of a delegate.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.CallByName
```